# Using Datepicker in bootstrap gives error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
<body>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="exampleInputEmail">Date From:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="DATEFROM" id="dateFrom" type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="exampleInputEmail">Date To:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="DATETO" id="dateTo" type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready,Datepicker code below
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Initially there is a body tag in which date fields are given named as Date from and Date to field.

After that i have included some scripts as i am writing my project in bootstrap.
The last script is meant for datepicker

But when i load my page, datepicker doesn't come up in ie but works perfectly fine in chrome
**It gives error that Object doesn't support method or property 'datepicker'**

[image: Error: Object doesn't support method or property datepicker]

Comment: by the way why are you loading two jquerys?

Comment: You have 2 versions of `jquery` referred! keep the latest one!!

Comment: The issue is the jquery loading, i have an example for you https://jsfiddle.net/mhoppchc/

Comment: Thanks @Jim it worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue will be entirely related to you loading 2 seperate versions of jquery.

Your code works with one version loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/329suzv9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm @Reece Sheppard